# Call change and click event together jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not able to access skills value using id while I can access finduserType value.

I don't know why, It should call on change event and click event as well.

```js
  $(function() {


    $("#findUserType").change(function () {
        var user_type = $("#findUserType").val();
        var skills = $("#skills").val();
        var phone = $("#phones").val();

    var src = '{{Request::root()}}/api/user/suggestion/email';
    var srcPhone = '{{Request::root()}}/api/user/suggestion/phone';


   /* var skills = $("#skills").val();

    var phone = $("#phones").val();*/
    // Load the Users from the server, passing the usertype as an extra param
    $("#skills").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: src,
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : skills,
                    user_type : user_type
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        min_length: 3,
        delay: 300
    });

    // Load the Users from phone to the server, passing the usertype as an extra param
    $("#phones").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: srcPhone,
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : phone,
                    user_type : user_type
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        min_length: 3,
        delay: 300
    });

  });  

});
```

```html
<form>
    <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="findUserType" name="finduser">
            <option value="">--Select--</option>
            <option value="2">D</option>
            <option value="3">P</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="skills" class="form-control">
        <input type="text" id="phones" class="form-control" name="phone">
    </div>
</form>
```

Updated the code please take a look what exactly i'm going to stuck it does not take email's values. When I call ajax change event does work fine but skills value does not have the any value. Also suggest how can i compress this code. I just want to check on change event call ajax base on skills and phone values.

Comment: You have a typo in your JavaScript code.  You're closing the first event handler assignment all the way at the end of the code instead of at the end of the event handler.  So the other event handlers are considered to be *inside* that first function.  (Hint: Formatting your code and using sensible indentation makes this obvious.)

Comment: It is a bad idea to define event handlers within another event handler. Not only will the inner event handlers not be active until the first event occurs, it will accumulate many equal event handlers when the first event gets repeated: so: Do not nest event handlers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work better:

```js
$("#findUserType").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "") {
    $("#textboxes").hide();
  } else {
    $("#textboxes").show();
  }

});

$("#skills").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: src,
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        term: $("#skills").val(),
        user_type: $("#findUserType").val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        response(data);
      }
    });
  },
  min_length: 3,
  delay: 300
});

// Load the Users from phone to the server, passing the usertype as an extra param
$("#phones").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: srcPhone,
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        term: $("#phones").val(),
        user_type: $("#findUserType").val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        response(data);
      }
    });
  },
  min_length: 3,
  delay: 300
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select class="form-control" id="findUserType" name="finduser">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option value="2">Doctor</option>
        <option value="3">Pharmacy</option>
    </select>
  <br/>
  <div id="textboxes" hidden>
    <input type="text" id="skills" class="form-control">
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="phones" class="form-control" name="phone">
  </div>
</form>
```

At present your two later autocomplete handlers are not bound until the "findUserType"'s "change" event has happened at least once, because they are declared within that code block. And also if that "change" event happens multiple times then multiple handlers will be attached to the other two elements, and then when those events are triggered, multiple copies of the code will run - I doubt that's what you intended.

Comment: I want to call ajax based on change event so i need the both textbox value on bases finduserType change event

Comment: current lyI'm getting blank value in term
email?term=&user_type=2

Comment: @Amy are you sure you want the phone value on click event of the textbox?

Comment: doesn't matter if it get click event or keychange but i want to grab the texboxes value of skills and phone when i change findUserType selection.

Comment: @Amy then you have to only write the code for findusertype change handler where you can get those values.

Comment: @Amy you can still do that if you like - see my edit. You don't have to wait for an event to fire on those elements. But you might want to check that they are populated before submitting to ajax.

Comment: Understand code updated what exactly i have and getting nothing value in skills and phone val() take a glance now

Comment: Did you type anything into the boxes before you changed an item in the "select"? If you didn't, then it's no surprise you got no values. Like I said, you have to check first that they are populated before you send anything to the server. Also you appear to have made the same mistake again and put your "autocomplete" definitions inside the "change" event, which is a bad idea.

Comment: if i put it outside the then autocomplete says undefine user_type

Comment: yes it will, but you can just use `$("#findUserType").val()` in place of that to get the value directly at the time the autocomplete runs. If you need that value populated in order for the autocomplete to succeed perhaps it makes sense to hide the textboxes until the user has chosen something from the dropdown?

Comment: I have amended the answer with an example which uses that idea.

Answer (score 2):

The change handler for #skills and the click handler for #phone will only be registered after the first change event firing on #findUserType.

Move those two handlers outside of #findUserType's change handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#findUserType").change(function () {

        var user_type = $(this).val();
    });

        $("#skills").change(function () {
            var skills = $(this).val();
            var phone = $("#phones").val();
        });

        $("#phone").change(function () {
            var phone = $(this).val();
        });

      });
```

I hope you this will help you get the values of skills and phone when user type is selected.